# Find the number of tuples consisting of $0, 1$ and $3$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How can I find the number of tuples $(k_1, k_2, ...,k_{26})$ such that each $k_i$ equals $0, 1$ or $3$ and $k_1 + k_2 + ... + k_{26} = 15$.

I can reduce this problem to finding the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in expression $(1 + x + x^3)^{26}$, but I do not now any simple way to do it.

Comment: I'd work off the number of $3's$.  If, say, there are five $3's$ then all the rest are $0$ so we have $\binom {26}{5}$.  And so on.

Comment: @lulu, thanks! In this case it works well (only 6 cases), but is there any general approach to such problems?

Comment: I'd say the generating function approach is about as good as it gets as a general method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can successively use the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)* to extract the coefficient. It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a polynomial.

> We obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{15}](1 + x + x^3)^{26}&=[x^{15}]\sum_{k=0}^{26}\binom{26}{k}x^{3k}(1+x)^{26-k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{26}{k}[x^{15-3k}](1+x)^{26-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{26}{k}[x^{15-3k}]\sum_{j=0}^{26-k}\binom{26-k}{j}x^{j}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{26}{k}\binom{26-k}{15-3k}\tag{2}\\
> &=853423740
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and the rule $$[x^{n-k}]P(x)=[x^n]x^kP(x)$$
  We also set the upper limit of the index $k$ to $5$, since the exponent of $x^{15-3k}$ is non-negative.
- In (2) we select the summand with $j=15-3k$ to obtain the coefficient of $x^{15-3k}$.

Comment: You can jump right to (2) by using @lulu’s comment on the original question: Choose $0\le k\le5$ positions to place $3$’s. The total of the $3$’s is then $3k$, and to reach $15$ by filling the remaining $26-k$ positions with $0$’s and $1$’s, choose $15-3k$ of the remaining positions to place $1$’s.

Comment: @SteveKass: Yes, no doubt, a nice approach. I just wanted to demonstrate the technique of iterated coefficient extraction. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so you have options: Lets say you have $a$ 1s and $b$ 3s, and the remainder are zeros.  So you have that $a+3b = 15$.  This gives the following collection of $(a,b)$ pairs as solutions:
$$ (15,0), (12, 1), (9,2), (6,3), (3,4), (0,5),$$
or equivalently, $(15-3k, k)$ for $0 \leq k \leq 5$.

Now from a pair $(a,b)$ you obtain solutions to the original equation by choosing, from the 26 positions, $a$ places to put a 1, and from the remaining $26-a$ positions, $b$ places to put a $0$.  In other words, you have contribution of ${26 \choose a}{26-a \choose b}$ from the pair $(a,b)$.  This gives a total of
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{5} {26 \choose 15 -3k}{26-3k \choose k}.$$
This gives the same result as in the answer of Markus.

Comment: Nice presentation! (+1)